# Is google cloud iot enabling devices to communicate locally as aws greengrass does?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iot

So I have a product built using aws greengrass core and aws iot core. And I'm trying to migrate to Google Cloud Platform. I saw that basically, google cloud iot does the same thing as aws iot core. But I can't really find a google brick with a feature that enable devices to share data when they are not connected to the internet. Is it integrated with cloud iot core ? Or there is no equivalent features on google cloud ?

Comment: Are you looking for the same implementation as AWS IoT *Device Shadowing* (origin doc source [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-device-shadows.html)) in Google Cloud IoT?

Comment: @Nick_Kh not really. I mostly talk about the first feature on this page [here](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/greengrass/features/).

Comment: I assume that once device is going offline there should be some edge unit that will gather streaming data to sync up it with the central core IoT for further processing. Is it correct presumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not natively. IoT Core from AWS and GCP have very similar capabilities, but GCP does not have any equivalent to Greengrass. You could implement this manually and still use GCP IoT Core, and leverage [Gateways](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/gateways) to implement the local bridge to GCP, but you have to do the heavy lifting of how to authenticate devices locally and handle the buffering and message brokering.

You can implement some of that logic and East/West traffic with the [LFEdge](https://www.lfedge.org/) projects such as EdgeX Foundry or FLEdge, and Open Horizon, but that seems out of scope of your question.