# Can devices share data to each other through the gateway on Google cloud iot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, iot, google-cloud-iot

I have previously used a cloud iot service on amazon named greengrass core. And it was able to enable devices to share data to each other offline. And I just read the doc of the gateway of google cloud iot core. And I was wondering if this gateway is just an additional security layer or if it an equivalent for aws greengrass core. Can the gateway enable devices to share data to each other offline, or it's just meant for the communication between devices and cloud iot core ?

Comment: What do you mean by "share data to each other offline"? If a device is offline, it cannot communicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is google cloud iot enabling devices to communicate locally as aws greengrass does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66317777/is-google-cloud-iot-enabling-devices-to-communicate-locally-as-aws-greengrass-do)

Comment: Are you looking for the same implementation as AWS IoT *Device Shadowing* (origin doc source [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-device-shadows.html)) in Google Cloud IoT?

Comment: @Tarmo actually aws greengrass core can enable devices to share data to each other locally when they are not connected to the internet. And when the connection is up again, the core send it to the cloud. So my question is to know if the gateway on google iot can do the same work

Comment: @SerhiiRohoza not really (I asked this question)

Comment: @Nick_Kh not really. I mostly talk about the first feature on this page [here](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/greengrass/features/).

Comment: I assume that once device is going offline there should be some edge unit that will gather streaming data to sync up it with the central core IoT for further processing. Is it correct presumption?

Comment: @Nick_Kh exactly !

Comment: The cloud IoT Gateway is just a secure bridge between the device and core IoT service, hence it doesn't bring any additional middleware layer for collecting data and further synchronizing likewise AWS Greengrass intend to perform. If you have more interest in developing this feature, feel free to file a request via vendor's [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). Does it answer your question?